# Using ascx file from Azure Blob storage

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-blob-storage, ascx

I'm trying to store user controls (ASCX) into Azure Blob (since I need to update them very often).

I use ParseControl. [However, it doesn't cause compilation such as PlaceHolder.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7072503/296861)

**Question:** Is there anyway I can access file from Blob like [Page.LoadControl("MyControl.ascx");](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ecy7tf.aspx)

My last option is to write into [temporary file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7075187/296861) if nothing work.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest for you will be to create one custom [VirtualPathProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider.aspx). You can take [this sample](http://jvshangout.wordpress.com/2012/02/17/virtualpathprovider-for-windows-azure-hosting-aspx-web-pages-in-blob-storage/) as a starting point.

Then just call Page.LoadControl("~/Your_Registered_Path/Control.ascx")