# Load uncompiled user control / page from Azure Blob

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have published website on azure. Let say I have one new client subscribes so what i want to do add one customize page (aspx&aspx.cs) or user control files then I will upload it on azure blob storage. That publish file then download that page or user control from blob and show it.

is there any way?

Comment: I would consider that a security flaw.

Comment: Depends on what your application is about.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using ascx file from Azure Blob storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646944/using-ascx-file-from-azure-blob-storage)

Comment: Check the referenced similar question on SO. It doesn't really matter what you put on the storage - ASCX or ASPX.

Comment: I believe this *isn't* a duplicate, because it appears that VirtualPathProviders can't be used for uncompiled code (`.aspx.cs`). Is that true? If so, is there another solution?